# setDefaultNightMode() only works after second call in PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, preferencefragment, android-night-mode, android-dark-theme

I am working to implement a dark mode into my app. Right now I try to switch the UI mode between light and dark using a `PreferenceFragment` nested inside an `AppCompatActivity`. The App behaves like this, starting from the light theme as a default value:

- If I select 'dark' in the ListPreference, the summary of the
  preference changes, but the UI stays light in this and all the other activities.
- If I select 'dark' a second time, the activity switches to dark theme, as well as the other activities in the backstack.
- The same thing happens in reverse, when I want to switch back to the light theme.

So basically everything works, but you have to select the desired value in the ListPreference twice. The code for the ListPreference:

```
final Preference listPreferenceDesign = findPreference(PREF_DESIGN);
listPreferenceDesign.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
            if (((ListPreference) preference).getValue().equals("light")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            } else if (((ListPreference) preference).getValue().equals("dark")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
            return true;
    }
});
```

What I tried so far:

- Call `getActivity.recreate()`before the `return true;` statement
- Call `getActivity.recreate()`after a short delay using a `Handler`
- Call `this.recreate()` in the `onResume()` method of the parent Activity when a boolean `changedDesignSetting` was true

I am thankful for further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally get it to work using an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the parent activity. Now the code in the parent activity goes like this:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.settingsPlaceholderID, preferenceFragment).commit();
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener sharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(PREF_DESIGN)) {
            if (sharedPreferences.getString(key, "light").equals("light")) {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            } else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            }
        }
    }
};

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
```

And in the PreferenceFragment I only have:

```
final Preference listPreferenceDesign = findPreference(PREF_DESIGN);
listPreferenceDesign.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {           
        return true;
    }
});
```